# Creating lines with multiple vertices from CSV file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv, polyline-creation, vertices

[image]

I want to draw a line with the points as vertices, the stretch name is also given. This is merely a snippet of a larger dataset, is there any tool in QGIS which will convert these vertices into a single line (and replicate that for the entire dataset based on the `"Stretch"` column)?